# How can Lambda be a function of something in a Poisson distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution

I am reading the paper "Media Exposure through the Funnel: A Model of Multi-Stage Attribution" by Abhishek et al., (2012). Link: http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1399&context=heinzworks

They write "N is drawn from a Poisson distribution with a rate parameter λ, which is a function of the current state s, and advertising activity x" (P.12). But how can the lambda in a Poisson distribution a function of something?

Can anyone please explain this.

Comment: If I take a random sample of 10 Poisson random variables, each having rate 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, then each individually can be said to have a Poisson distribution, but they are not IID (independent, identically distributed). It sounds like you expect to collapse the modeled sample and visually see a Poisson distribution. That would not be the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy. Imagine that the number of times you cough in a minute when having cold is from Poisson distribution, where $\lambda$ is the intensity. Now imagine that the intensity depends the number of days you were sick $d_t$ and the number of antibiotic pill you took $m_t$: $\lambda_t=\lambda(d_t,m_t)$

The number of time you coughed at time $t$ is a random variable: 
$$x_t\sim Poisson(\lambda_t)$$
The distribution parameter depends on some variables, but the actual realization is random. You'll see that the average times you cough changes with time, maybe increases in first couple of days, then decreases:
$$E[x_t]=\lambda(d_t,m_t)$$